# htaccess redirect if does not start with folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to create a white list folder and redirect all others requests to index

```
url.com/public/.* <-- Can access to file on public folder
url.com/xxxx <-- redirect to index.php
```

I use this .htaccess **(but it doesn't work on 1and1 '500 Error')**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule !^public/.* index.php [L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule !^public /index.php [L]
```

Comment: nop, because i can access to `url.com/i_m_a_confidential_and_existing_file`

Comment: Yes, it works ! actually by adding `RewriteBase /` into my htaccess the 500 error is gone